12v heating element for hot water
I would like to know if it's feasible to use a 12v heating element, typically used for camping kettles, to heat water for use in a caravan shower. The idea is for offgrid camping as have a 12v leisure battery but no gas boiler.

Is it possible?
What would energy usage estimates and battery drain be?


is it possible? is not a useful question because it has a yes answer almost always

energy usage depends on what you are heating and to what temperature

What's the wattage or ohms of the heater?

First: this isn't really a home improvement question, but I'm feeling game to help teach you to fish on this one, so here goes. I'd put it in a comment but it's too long for that.
The answer: Kind of, but it's not an amazing plan. There's two big challenges here: energy and time.
Heating water is one of the biggest domestic energy users around. Heating up 15L of water from 10C ambient to 40C for shower use will take 0.6kWh or more of energy, depending on how well insulated the container you're using is. That's going to be a rather short shower, and not on the piping hot side, but decent. However, 0.6kWh is a fair bit of battery power. A good sized portable battery like an Ecoflow Delta 2 will let you extract a little bit less than 1kWh of energy, so heating up the water for that shower takes significantly more than half of your battery. If you're using typical AGM batteries, a hefty 12V 100Ah AGM in good shape holds enough energy that you would use about half of your battery capacity to heat for that shower. Either way, it's a lot, but not impossible to be off grid with enough solar and sunny weather. If it's overcast or raining, good luck.
The second challenge is time. 12V kettles tend to be somewhere in the 100W territory. So delivering that 0.6kWh of power will take you six hours. You could use more heating elements or a bigger element, but batteries typically can give out less energy when it's done at higher rates. And there will be a balance, because if you use too small of an element you'll be giving up too much heat from whatever container you're using to hold the water while you heat it.
All of this is why caravans tend to use gas for heating. It's much more energy dense and can heat more quickly, at the cost of adding a lot of complexity to the heating process to keep it safe.
One other option is a solar shower or direct solar water heating. Since energy from the sun is free, it matters a lot less how much energy is used to heat the water. Even if you then heat the water electrically, starting with much warmer water reduces the amount of energy and time needed.
Here is a water heating calculator if you want to play with the scenarios yourself. Don't use the default of 100% efficiency in your calculations. Electric heating is 100% efficient, but since you'll lose energy from the container the overall process of heating water is not that efficient. 90% is a good start for an insulated heater, 60% is probably a good start for an uninsulated container.

Heating enough water with a battery is hard on the battery and the heater.  They are not made for that much heating.
Use the battery to power a recirculating pump and use the sun/wood stove heat to heat the water. Can google for solar/wood heat water loops.
Either can heat up a 30 or 40 gallon hot water tank.
Keep the 12v heater to heat up a cup for coffee/tea/soup.

Sure it's possible. A candle will heat a warehouse, if the warehouse is insulated sufficiently, and the candle is big enough.
Similarly, a small heating element will heat a tank of water, if the tank is insulated sufficiently, and there is a large enough power supply to run the heater long enough. The number of gallons of water in the heater, how cold the water is at startup, and how hot you want the water at use also influence the size of the power supply needed.
The amps drawn by the heater become amp-hours over the time the heater is run. This in turn defines the draw on the battery. The kind and size of battery determines how many amp-hours it will supply. Note that lead acid batteries can only give half their rated amp-hours without too much damage to the battery, and high amp-hour draw can reduce a battery's total amp-hour availability lower than what is stamped on the tin.
A BTU is the amount of heat energy required to heat one pound of water 1 degree Fahrenheit, and 1 watt = 3.41 BTU/hour. A gallon (8.33 pounds) of water requires 8.33 BTU, or 2.44 watts for an hour, to heat 1 degree F. (If I have my math right.)
Take the number of gallons in your heater, multiply by the number of degrees F you need to increase, then multiply by 2.44, to get the watts of electricity you need to run for one hour to complete the heating cycle. Then divide by voltage to get the amps needed for an hour.
Example: The heater is 12VDC, and the tank is 30 gallons, filled with 60 degree F water. You want the water to be 110 degrees for the shower. That's a 50 degree increase. So:
30 x 50 x 2.44 = 3660 watts for an hour, / 12 = 305 amps for an hour.
You can divide more if you're willing to wait for more than an hour.
With the example above, a 12 hour heating time requires 25.4 amps steady for 12 hours, expending 300-ish watts. Either way, that's a big battery.
If your heater is smaller than the calculations called for, then decrease the current draw and increase the expected heating time proportionately. (example: A 50 watt heater will take 1/6 of the amps a 300 watt heater would, and would take 6 times longer to heat the water.)
Keep in mind there is no loss of heat due to less-than-perfect insulation or wire resistance losses calculated.
Is your water heater tank sufficiently insulated? Does your battery have enough amp hours to run the heater long enough to heat the amount of water from its starting cold to its desired hot? You can calculate what is needed and see if your heater can do it.
Note, since you're off-grid camping, I strongly suspect you will not be able to carry the size of battery you would need to the campsite. More like you'll need to truck or helicopter it in. A car battery will never cut it, and they're too uncomfortably heavy already. Perhaps a solar heating setup might do better?
